# add Family ID Column on Family Relations Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parent-child, recursive-query

I have a table in my source database that relates a person to his wife / husband and to their children (if they have any).

The relation to the children can go through the wife or the husband, but there is only a relation from one of the adults to the children, and only one relation between the husband and wife. It's not necessarily the same adult that have the relation to the spouse as the one to the child/children.

I want to create an output where i have each person and a unique id of their family. But i cant seem to wrap my head around how to get the result.

Below sample of my source data.

```
+--------+------+
| FromID | ToID |
+--------+------+
|      1 |    2 |
|      2 |    3 |
|      2 |    4 |
|      5 |    6 |
|      6 |    7 |
|      8 |    9 |
+--------+------+

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Relations](
            [FromID] [int] NULL,
            [ToID] [int] NULL
        ) 
        INSERT [dbo].[Relations] ([FromID], [ToID]) VALUES (1, 2)
        INSERT [dbo].[Relations] ([FromID], [ToID]) VALUES (2, 3)
        INSERT [dbo].[Relations] ([FromID], [ToID]) VALUES (2, 4)
        INSERT [dbo].[Relations] ([FromID], [ToID]) VALUES (5, 6)
        INSERT [dbo].[Relations] ([FromID], [ToID]) VALUES (6, 7)
        INSERT [dbo].[Relations] ([FromID], [ToID]) VALUES (8, 9)
```

In this sample data:

- person 1 is married to person 2 and person 2 has 2 children (3,4) (family of 4)
- Person 5 is married to person 6 and person 6 has 1 child (7) (family of 3)
- Person 8 is married to person 9, the have no children (family of 2)

And Below is the desired result:

```
+----------+----------+
| PersonID | FamilyID |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |
|        2 |        1 |
|        3 |        1 |
|        4 |        1 |
|        5 |        2 |
|        6 |        2 |
|        7 |        2 |
|        8 |        3 |
|        9 |        3 |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Your sample data does make a lot of sense. You have values in ToID that don't exist. Perhaps you need to take a look at this article for some good ideas on what you should post. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Do you have a table `Persons`?  Have you try a recursive query?

Comment: any SQL attempts to show some effort on your end?

Comment: You will also need to determine how many relations out you want to go. Since you do not document the type of relationship, you will not be able to determine spouse vs children.

Comment: If you wanted to make it a bit more robust you could do another table that had a primary key, FamilyID and RelationshipID. RelationshipID is made up of 1 for son and 2 for daughter or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to achieve this result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  COALESCE(h.husband, d.dependents) AS id,
  COALESCE(d.familyid, h.familyid) AS familyid
FROM (SELECT
            r.ToID AS dependents,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(r2.Fromid, r.Fromid)) AS familyid
      FROM Relations r
      LEFT JOIN Relations r2
        ON r.[FromID] = r2.ToID) d
FULL JOIN (SELECT
              COALESCE(r2.Fromid, r.Fromid) AS husband,
              DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(r2.Fromid, r.Fromid)) AS familyid
           FROM Relations r
           LEFT JOIN Relations r2
             ON r.[FromID] = r2.ToID) h
  ON d.dependents = h.husband
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out the husband of each family and assign and ID. You look for the ID not appearing as `[FromID]`

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/KAAEG85730)**

```
WITH husband as (      
    SELECT R1.[FromID] as [ID],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY R1.[FromID]) as rn
    FROM [Relations] R1
    LEFT JOIN [Relations] R2
      ON R1.[FromID] = R2.[ToID]
    WHERE R2.[FromID] IS NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM husband
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Then just use a recursive query to get all the family members for that [ID]

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

**EDIT:**

Because your tree only have two levels depth you can do it using `JOINS` but I can see problems if you want handle single parent family.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/VAJMU42992)**

```
WITH husbands as (      
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY R1.[FromID]) as [familyID],
            R1.[FromID] as [ID]           
    FROM [Relations] R1
    LEFT JOIN [Relations] R2
      ON R1.[FromID] = R2.[ToID]
    WHERE R2.[FromID] IS NULL
), wifes as (
    SELECT H.[familyID], R1.[ToID] as [ID]
    FROM husbands H
    JOIN Relations R1
      ON H.[ID] = R1.[FromID] 
), childrens as (
    SELECT H.[familyID], R2.[ToID] as [ID]
    FROM husbands H
    JOIN Relations R1
      ON H.[ID] = R1.[FromID] 
    JOIN Relations R2
      ON R1.[ToID] = R2.[FromID]     
)    
SELECT * FROM husbands UNION 
SELECT * FROM wifes UNION 
SELECT * FROM childrens
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]